# Active Directory - How to Escape Comma in CN

Tags: c#, active-directory

How do I escape the comma character in the below AD path (Smith, John)? I have tried using backslash but that gives the error: "Unrecognized escape sequence"

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry();
entry.Path = "LDAP://domain/CN=Smith, John, OU=Distribution...
```

Comment: You can't escape `,` because it doesn't require escaping. There is nothing in your string that needs escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backslash to escape (comma need escape):

```
"LDAP://domain/CN=Smith\\, John, OU=Distribution..."
```

May be you just put "\" instead of "\\" before?
In C# you need "\\" to specify a backslash.